# Can you trust the New Relic "Page average load time"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

Using: rails 3.2.11 and New Relic (free version).

I have had some problems with an app being quite slow. I have examined it and speeded up my app quite a lot. According to New Relic the app is still very slow, especially in the rendering phase. See pic: [image: New Relice screen dump]

According to Pingdom however, it seems to be loading in the matter of 2-4 seconds which is my experience when I visit the website as well.

I am using Memcachier and this speeds up the pages a lot but maybe New Relic always counts for un-cached controller runs?

My big question is, can you trust the New Relic "Average page load time" as a key to how slow your website really is? Would you trust the results of Pingdom more?

Comment: Pingdom doesn't load the entire dom, including javascript and CSS. It looks like your app is spending most time in DOM processing and Page Rendering. Does your app feel like you need to wait a bit before it's done processing?

Comment: Yes! If the page load time is high, it is quite often related to 'wait' according to Pingdom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Relic measures browser experience of real-world users from all over the globe with various connection speeds, browsers, and computers. As Jesse mentioned, comparing RUM with Pingdom isn't an apples to apples comparison. It's also unlikely that real-world experience on your website will match your experience and that's why RUM is so useful.

There are many ways to test the performance of a web page including webpagetest.org and [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/). These tools might give you some more information about why your page is taking longer to load than you expect.

With access to the full suite of New Relic tools, you can access a geographic breakdown of page load time as described here: https://newrelic.com/docs/mobile-apps/geography-dashboard where you might discover that connections from a certain location are skewing your results unexpectedly. You can also access the browsers breakdown as described here: https://newrelic.com/docs/site/browsers where you might find that one particular browser is exceptionally slow for your page. If it's related to a browser, that's something you can certainly address. If it's just geography, you can rest easily knowing there's not much you can do beside perhaps a CDN which addresses connectivity issues in that location.

On the web transactions tab, you can see the browser performance by transaction even with a free subscription and that might help you see that one page is much slower than you realized and give you a target for optimization.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that New Relic was an actual Real User Monitor. I thought it was all computer generated. So, basically this means that I should trust NR over Pingdom (and other similar services) as to how fast the website really is, right?

Comment: I think New Relic's RUM data is more representative of real user experiences. Pingdom is useful data for observing changes in your response time especially when your app is receiving low throughput from users.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it's pretty accurate. What it does is inject some JavaScript in the footer of your page, and measures the difference between the time of the event like clicking links and submitting forms, and the page ready event. See here for more information: https://newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work